# How do I remove an open ID?

Tags: support, openid, gmail

I tried to move my OpenID from Google to Google Apps and, probably as a result of not following the instructions carefully enough, I now have a primary OpenID which points to my Google Apps account and an alt OpenID which points to my old Gmail account.

In the interests of security, I'd like to remove the alt OpenID (which points to the old Gmail account) but I'm unable to find any option to delete it.

I don't want to delete the account.

"Change OpenID" only allows me to change the primary one (which I don't want to do) and "Edit" doesn't give me the option to delete the alt OpenID.

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [no way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71188/can-we-delete-our-own-alternate-openid) to delete an openID via the accounts page, I'd recommend you send an email to `team@superuser.com` requesting them to remove an openID ( and do mention which one!)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Sathya's answer, you can remove the SU authorization from your google account here: https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens Log in with your google account and revoke access for superuser.com/meta.superuser.com/etc.

This will disallow automatic openID access for superuser.com logins.

Comment: Good point, thanks very much.