# How can I move my Super User account associated with one Google to another Google account?

Tags: discussion, openid, stackexchange, google

I switched my Google account which I used to log me into superuser.com

This currently is my only way to access superuser (old google account). My question is: how can I associate my new account with my superuser.com account.

Is it maybe possible to grant Facebook access, then delete the old Google association and link my account here with my new Google account?

In short this is my login scenario:

- **Current log in:** old@gmail.com
- **Desired log in:** new@gmail.com

Comment: What's your other account, they can be merged if need be

Comment: Have you tried clicking "add openid" in your user prifle page?

Answer (score 4):

I hope that I found the answer in [this post](https://meta.superuser.com/a/1937/167207).

Basically now I added my other Google Account as Google Profile via "add openid" like Daniel suggested. The next step will be to contact the staff of Stack Exchange/Super User like the linked post from above suggests:

> There's no way to delete an openID via the accounts page, I'd
>   recommend you send an email to team@superuser.com requesting them to
>   remove an openID ( and do mention which one!)

Comment: while you cannot delete it, you can overwrite & hence delete it